# How to add custom facters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facter

I have file text  structured as follows

key1,value1

I want to add these key values as facters in my host. I have splitted those key (configs[0]) , values (configs[1]). How to add those to facters using ruby. I have tried following code but not succeeded

`configs = File.read("........configuration.txt").split(",").map(&:strip)`

```
Facter.add(configs[0]){
            setcode { configs[1])
            }
```

Regards,
Malintha

Comment: please add more details

Comment: basically i want to know how to add custom facter in ruby scrpt

Comment: What is a facter? (I'm not trying to troll)